# Identify when Leaflet Draw cancel button is clicked

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

## Problem

I'm using [leaflet draw](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html) for my application, and I have the 'remove' button active. The remove button has three options:

1. <kbd>Save</kbd>
2. <kbd>Cancel</kbd>
3. <kbd>Clear All</kbd>

I want function `foo()` to be called if the user clicks <kbd>Save</kbd>, however, I want function `bar()` to be called should they click <kbd>Cancel</kbd>.

[Live demo](https://codepen.io/edprince/pen/vZoZay?editors=0110)

## Solution

I know this could be achieved by simply giving it an ID, and adding an event listener, but it's not as clean as I think it should be.

## Ideal Solution

Leaflet draw its own methods for detecting when the buttons are pressed but it seems to me they only do it for one level higher. For example:

> `draw:deletestop` The type of edit this is. One of: remove Triggered when the user has finished removing shapes (remove mode) and saves.
>
> - [Leaflet Docs](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-event-draw:deletestop)

This allows me to call `foo()` after the user has selected **any** of the three options, rendering that they have simply finished dealing with the remove button interaction.

I cannot find a way in the docs to be able to listen for leaflet draw firing an event on the individual buttons being pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler for the cancel/disable function is stored as part of your `L.Control.Draw` instance. So, you you can modify the handler right after you instantiate your `L.Control.Draw` object:

```
var myDrawControl = new L.Control.Draw();

myDrawControl._toolbars.edit.disable =  function () {
  if (!this.enabled()) {
    /* If you need to do something right as the
       edit tool is enabled, do it here right
       before the return */
    return;
  }

  this._activeMode.handler.revertLayers();
  /* If you need to do something when the
     cancel button is pressed and the edits
     are reverted, do it here. */
  L.Toolbar.prototype.disable.call(this);
};
```

The source for the handler is [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/v0.4.12/src/edit/EditToolbar.js#L129-L139) and while this works well, you will have to be careful with future versions of Leaflet.Draw that may change the handler's functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The newest version of Leaflet.draw 0.4.14 you can use

> map.on('draw:toolbarclosed', function(){ //Add code here});

Comment: This doesn't neccesarily mean that the Cancel button is clicked. 

For example in my L.Control.Draw object I have `repeatMode: true`which means that this fires every time I add a point